# SQL Server and Continuous Integration

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We have a huge SQL Server database (~1TB). Our DB deploy only target the objects changed/created. i.e let's say out of 500 stored procedure, if there is a change in 2-3 procedures, we deploy only those 3 procedures in production.

We maintain our DB objects in source code repository. So, if we need to rollback a change, we can easily.

I need suggestions on how we can automate our DB deploys taking in consideration the rollback process(we might need it at some point).With database being huge, backup and restore is not an option.

We use Jenkins as primary CI tool.

Thoughts?